# Styling of first label within a tag

Tags: html, css

I want to style the first label in `<p>` tag.

I want first label font size 20px while 2nd label size 10px. I know by using ids and classess. But I want like

```
p->first:label
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must share HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

```
p label { font-size:10px;}
p label:first-child { font-size:20px;}
```

Comment: Does not match if there is any element inside the `p` before the first `label`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `first-child`

```
p label:first-child
{
 /* your style */
}
```

Comment: Thanks all members for giving answer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to actually use `:first-of-type`, so:

```
p > label { font-size: 10px; }
p > label:first-of-type { font-size: 20px; }
```

Comment: This works if the `label` is a child of the `p`, but not if the `label` is wrapped inside an some other element, as in `<p><span ...><label>...</label></span>...</p>`

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/8ud9B/)**

I suggest to use `nth-of-type()`

[Read here for more details](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

html

```
<p>
    <label>this is a label</label>
    <label>this is a label</label>
    <label>this is a label</label>
    <label>this is a label</label>
</p>
```

css

```
p label:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
```